# The native view manager required by name (ExpoLinearGradient) from NativeViewManagerAdapter isn't exported by expo-modules-core

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, linear-gradients

I try to use expo-linear-gradient in expo bareworkflow but I get this warning when I use LinearGradient. How to resolve it.

Comment: Did you install it with expo install or npm install?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @dev404 expo install

Comment: I am also having issues with this. It's working in storybook, but when I import the component to the actually app using expo, it's not working. 

"The native view manager required by name (ExpoLinearGradient) from NativeViewManagerAdapter isn't exported by expo-modules-core. Views of this type may not render correctly. Exported view managers: []"